# How can I get ByRef Arguments to work in a dynamically created assembly with Method.Invoke

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, scripting, vbcodeprovider

I have a text file that I am compiling into an assembly use the VBCodeProvider class

The file looks like this:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Class Script

    Public Sub AfterClockIn(ByVal clockNo As Integer, ByRef comment As String)
        If clockNo = 1234 Then
            comment = "Not allowed"
            MessageBox.Show(comment)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is the compile code:

```
Private _scriptClass As Object
Private _scriptClassType As Type

Dim codeProvider As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider()
Dim optParams As New CompilerParameters
optParams.CompilerOptions = "/t:library"
optParams.GenerateInMemory = True
Dim results As CompilerResults = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(optParams, code.ToString)
Dim assy As System.Reflection.Assembly = results.CompiledAssembly
_scriptClass = assy.CreateInstance("Script")
_scriptClassType = _scriptClass.GetType
```

What I want to do is to modify the value of the comment String inside the method, so that after I call it from code I can inspect the value:

```
Dim comment As String = "Foo"
Dim method As MethodInfo = _scriptClassType.GetMethod("AfterClockIn")
method.Invoke(_scriptClass, New Object() {1234, comment})
Debug.WriteLine(comment)
```

However comment is always `"Foo"` (message box shows `"Not Allowed"`), so it appears that the ByRef modifier is not working

If I use the same method in my code `comment` is correctly modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However comment is always "Foo" (message box shows "Not Allowed"), so it appears that the ByRef modifier is not working

It is, but you're using it incorrectly, with incorrect expectations :)

When you create the argument array, you're *copying the value* of `comment` into the array. After the method has completed, you no longer have access to the array, so you can't see that it's changed. That change in the array *won't* affect the value of `comment`, but demonstrates the `ByRef` nature. So what you want is:

```
Dim arguments As Object() = New Object() { 1234, comment }
method.Invoke(_scriptClass, arguments)
Debug.WriteLine(arguments(1))
```

Comment: (Apologies for any failures in the syntax of the first line, by the way. I can't easily check it right now.)

Comment: Yes I see that makes sense to me. Yes I figured it out:- there was an extra closing bracket in your code after the `comment }`

Comment: @MattWilko: Ah - that was left over from copying the end of the method invocation :)